# can we pass Listview with data to another class library project class in vb net

Tags: vb.net, list, view

I want to pass list view to another class library project class. I want all data in another class without loss of data and without change in original values. Is their any way??

Comment: This question is simultaneously in want of details and a specific problem.

Comment: A `ListView` is an object like any other. How do you usually pass an object around? Why would this be any different? Basically, you have assumed that it should be different for no reason instead of just trying what you already know how to do.

Comment: Must we??? `Public Class anotherclasslibraryprojectclass` `Public Property TheListView As ListView` `End Class` ... `Dim myanotherclasslibraryprojectclass As New anotherclasslibraryprojectclass()` `myanotherclasslibraryprojectclass.TheListView = ListView1`... Is this what you're asking about?